# JuMP & Julia - Vector optimization

Tags: julia, gurobi, julia-jump

Trying to work with JuMP and Julia with Gurobi solver I would like to minimize a vector of variable, but can't figure it out how to formulize it.

I have where `m` is my model name and `size_teachers` an integer:

```
@variable(m, days_worked_vec[1:size_teachers], Int)
```

which is a `size_teachers` vector length, and I would like to minimize each items of this vector. I tried to define:

```
for teacher in 1:size_teachers
    @objective(m, Min, days_worked_vec[teacher])
end
```

But it made the root relaxation infeasible, leading to a non optimal solution (no calculation performed).

Anyone know or have a clue on how to setup the `@objective` to minimize each elements of a vector?

Comment: You probably want to do a multi-objective optimization. In this case it is worth to investigate https://github.com/anriseth/MultiJuMP.jl package that is designed to handle such problems.

Comment: Single objective optimization could also be used to optimize a decision vector of abitrary dimension

Comment: @user172056 Can you explain how you would implement vector optimisation using a single objective ? When trying to pass a vector to `@objective`, it raise an error (int needed, not vect)